# When is @pytest.hookimpl executes

Tags: pytest

I am new to pytest. When is @pytest.hookimpl executes? And what is the complete usage of it? I have tried with logs. For (hookwrapper=true), it is printing, 3 sets of after and before yield for a single test.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

pytest uses `@pytest.hookimpl` just to label hook methods. (So `@pytest.hookimpl` is executed when pytest collects the hook method.)

If you read the source code of pytest, you can find these codes:

```
def normalize_hookimpl_opts(opts):
    opts.setdefault("tryfirst", False)
    opts.setdefault("trylast", False)
    opts.setdefault("hookwrapper", False)
    opts.setdefault("optionalhook", False)
```

It means pytest will label the hook method with `@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=False, trylast=False, hookwrapper=False, optionalhook=False)` by default. **Pytest will treat these hook methods in different ways according to this label(decorator) when executing them.**

Take the `hookwrapper` parameter for example. If the hook method is labeled as `hookwrapper=True`, pytest will execute the part before `yield` first and then execute other same type hook methods. After these methods executed, the part after `yield` will be executed. (This feature is just like pytest fixtures.)

One usage of `@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)` is that you can calculate the total cost time of some hook methods. 
(Here, the example code will calculate the tests collect time.)

```
@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_collection(session):
    collect_timeout = 5
    collect_begin_time = time.time()
    yield
    collect_end_time = time.time()
    c_time = collect_end_time - collect_begin_time
    if c_time > collect_timeout:
        raise Exception('Collection timeout.')
```

Comment: Another very good source of information for hooks is for pluggy, the plugin module which is base for pytest: http://pluggy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/